# Naive Bayes Assumption formal definition

Tags: naive-bayes

I am reading Andrew Ng's lecture notes available at http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes2.pdf on Naive Bayes assumption.

He writes

> For instance, if `y = 1` means *spam email*; “buy” is word 2087 and “price”
>   is word 39831; then we are assuming that if I tell you `y = 1` (that a
>   particular piece of email is spam), then knowledge of `x-2087`(knowledge of
>   whether “buy” appears in the message) will have no effect on your
>   beliefs about the value of `x-39831`(whether “price” appears). More
>   formally, this can be written as `p(x-2087|y) = p(x-2087|y, x-39831)` (Note
>   that this is not the same as saying that `x-2087` and `x-39831` are independent,
>   which would have been written `p(x-2087) = p(x-2087|x-39831)`; rather, we
>   are only assuming that `x-2087` and `x-39831` are conditionally
>   independent given `y`.)

What I am not able to understand is `p(x-2087|y) = p(x-2087|y, x-39831)`?!?!?!?!

Like, doesn't it translate to 
`p(x-2087|y) = p(x-2087|y) * p(x-39831)`

meaning that `p(x-39831) = 1`.

Like I am confused on knowing `y = 1` and the knowledge of `x-2087`, I shouldn't be able to guess on the presence or absence of `x-39831` so how did `p(x-39831)` gets to be `1` in all of that?

Sorry if this question sounds trivial, it's genuinely important for me.

Comment: "Like, doesn't it translate to p(x-2087|y) = p(x-2087|y) * p(x-39831)?" Why do you think so? I think it doesn't.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1925393/what-do-commas-mean-in-probability

Comment: Also this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/732736/269425

Comment: Your comma is on the other side of the conditional "|", so it's not the same situation as in that posting (the first one). The second one isn't about conditional probabilities at all.

Comment: What is it then?

Comment: I have used up my time for procrastination now, so I don't think about what else could be written instead of what you write, however my message is that your logic that led to your confusion is wrong.

Comment: Are you going to recharge your batteries now?